# Dojo grid goes hidden when grid is refreshed

Tags: grid, dojo, invisible

I am refreshing `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid` using `dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore` per second. I have a `dijit.layout.TabContainer` where `EnhancedGrid` is present in one of the tab. When I switched the tab and come back to grid tab, the whole `grid` disappears.

What can be the solution?

```js
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
    url: '',
    data: result,
    urlPreventCache: false
});
grid.setStore(store);
```

Comment: please show some more code, especially the part, where you 'refresh' the store or grid or whatever. Even better would be a fiddle reproducing the issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about using `EnhancedGrid` but I had the same error when I used `DataGrid` to create a dynamic and changing matrix and this is how I was able to fix it.

Your problem arises because:

1. Your old structure property in the grid doesn't support the new store (different fieldnames etc.). If you don't get the structure right, Dojo complains and you don't see a grid.
2. I'm pretty sure it's this one. `grid.setStore(newStore)` doesn't work the second time probably because `grid` adapts itself to the first declaration of the store. I had tried the `grid.setStore()` and `grid.setStructure()` methods and it didn't show up after the first "refresh".

My solution:

Empty your container with `dojo.empty()` and create a new grid in that container every time you refresh with your new store

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Deleting and recreating the whole grid won't be a feasible solution. Is there any other way of doing it?